# Foundation: small media query won't be displayed on smartphone

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, contao

I'm currently working on the [this](http://www.fabioscatering.de/) page. Can someone explain to me why the site won't be rendered correctly on a smartphone? The medium Query is shown instead of the small.

I integrated the foundation js-files like so:

```
<script src="files/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the css files (foundation, settings) are imported into my style.scss file.

I did the same on [another page](http://www.fsv-sport.de/neu/) but there everything is working well.

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: The second link is the same. The "hamburger" menu is appearing for a medium-sized window.

Answer (score 0):

I've inspected the Html content of the first page and you're using a class of `hide-for-large-up` for the mobile menu. This means that the menu will appear for all window widths that are not defined as large in the media queries.

I would suggest using `hide-for-medium-up` as generally you'd only want the mobile menu to appear for small screens. The `a` tag would then look like below:

```
<a class="mobile-navigation hide-for-medium-up" href="#offcanvas">
```

Also, it doesn't look like you've defined a navigation menu specifically for medium-sized content. When I shrink the window to a "medium" width, I see the "hamburger" mobile menu. If you want to specifically show content for a medium-sized screen, use a class of `show-for-medium-only`